# How do I point certain directory to /dev/null?

Tags: filesystems, directory

I am running CentOS with cPanel, which creates a custom log directory and writes the logs there. The result is that the IO for the hard disk goes sky high.

If I do `lsof` I got:

```
hostsite.com

httpd      2383    nobody 3779w   REG  253,0         0  422463 /usr/local/apache/domlogs/mygamecardotcobnao.super                  hostsite.com-bytes_log
httpd      2383    nobody 3780w   REG  253,0      5265  420994 /usr/local/apache/domlogs/myfreefreedatixuua.super                  hostsite.com
httpd      2383    nobody 3781w   REG  253,0        36  422464 /usr/local/apache/domlogs/myfreefreedatixuua.super                  hostsite.com-bytes_log
httpd      2383    nobody 3782w   REG  253,0      3101  415849 /usr/local/apache/domlogs/myfreedatingfrekeuo.supe                  rhostsite.com
httpd      2383    nobody 3783w   REG  253,0        72  422465 /usr/local/apache/domlogs/myfreedatingfrekeuo.supe                  rhostsite.com-bytes_log
httpd      2383    nobody 3784w   REG  253,0       672  419338 /usr/local/apache/domlogs/myfreedatingblogsxgo.sup                  erhostsite.com
httpd      2383    nobody 3785w   REG  253,0         0  422466 /usr/local/apache/domlogs/myfreedatingblogsxgo.sup
```

Disabling this domlog is impossible because there are tons of those lines automatically generated.

I just want to point `/usr/local/apache/domlogs/` to `/dev/null`. Can that be done?

Comment: Does it stop working if you remove permissions to that directory? (`chmod 0 /usr/local/apache/domlogs/`) or remove it altogether? Can you create those log **files** beforehand as symlinks to /dev/null?

Comment: maybe I should symlink domlogs to /dev/null

Comment: No idea if it's stable but nullfs might be something for you: https://github.com/xrgtn/nullfs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can afford some RAM, you can set up a RAM disk and let your logs go there:

```
mount -t tmpfs -o size=200M none /usr/local/apache/domlogs
```

Additionally, you should setup logrotate to rotate the logs every minute/hour/day/night/week/* and delete the old logs. This is not exactly what you want, but it should fix your problem as RAM I/O won't slow down your disks.

Comment: This would be the best solution IMHO.

Comment: I have huge ram. I simply do not need the log though. Interesting.

Comment: what would be the command to mount /usr/local/apache/domlogs to /dev/null instead?

Answer (score 2):

A not-very-good solution (the ones proposed in other answers are much better), but you could remove the directory and them symlink it to /dev/null. But then, applications might start failing when they try to write to that directory and find that it's not actually a directory.

Comment: how to do so? I really don't need this domlogs and there is no easy way for cpanel to just don't write those log.

Comment: Delete the directory (e.g. `rm -rf /usr/local/apache/domlogs`) and replace it by a symlink (`ln -s /dev/null /usr/local/apache/domlogs`).

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not, because `/dev/null` is a file ( devnode actually ), not a directory.  You can not create files inside it.  You will need to configure the app not to bother creating these logs.